# MigraDoc Footer Position

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdfsharp, migradoc

I am trying to place an image as the footer of each page, I can move the footer closer to the bottom of the page using:

```
doc.DefaultPageSetup.FooterDistance = "0cm"
```

But I cannot seem to find a way to allow a shorter distance from the sides of the page. Is there a way to do this or some kind of "trick" to achieve this.

The only way I can find is by removing the page setup margins, but I need them to hold the page together.

Does anyone know a way around this or some setting I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a TextFrame to the footer (`AddTextFrame()`) and assign an absolute position to this textframe.

See also:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=6928#p6928

Comment: Can you share an example please?

Comment: Will be nice if anybody shares the ideas you are interchanging (by telepathy) for those that does not have this skill yet  :D:D:D

Answer (score 0):

```
Document document = new Document();    
Section section = document.AddSection();    
Section.PageSetup.BottomMargin =  "1cm"; // according to data size

Paragraph paragraph = section.Footers.Primary.AddParagraph();     
paragraph.AddText("XYZ ltd");    
paragraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question which is about adding images and reducing the left margin. This code-only answer shows how to draw text with default left and right margins and is not useful in the context of this question.